# Converting DATETIME to a human readable date

Tags: datetime, php

I'm trying to convert the DATETIME to something that people can actually use. This is the date:

```
2013-09-05 11:52:10
```

I'm using:

```
date("D, d M Y", '2013-09-05 11:52:10');
```

Is turning into:

```
Thu, 01 Jan 1970
```

Makes no sense to me.

Comment: The second argument needs to be an int timestamp http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: What's not human readable about `2013-09-05 11:52:10`?

Answer (score 7):

You need to turn the date into a timestamp before passing it to date()

```
$time = strtotime('2013-09-05 11:52:10');
echo date("D, d M Y", $time);
```

Comment: I really detest the `strtottime()` function. If you know the input format, it is far better to use `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()`. But better yet, just use MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, and you won't have to do any kind of conversion first.

Answer (score 5):

Is this supposed to be PHP code? If so, the correct is

```
date("D, d M Y", strtotime('2013-09-05 11:52:10'));
```

If this has to do with MySql, the correct function to use is [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) (however, what you have is invalid MySql syntax). Please clarify.

Comment: I really detest the `strtottime()` function. If you know the input format, it is far better to use `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()`. But better yet, just use MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, and you won't have to do any kind of conversion first.

Comment: @Spudley: I dislike it as well, but there's a serious counter-argument: it works. It's *documented* to work. As an engineer I have to put that over personal preference every time.

Comment: Both of the other alternatives are documented to work better. Particularly `CreateFormFormat()` which was created specifically to improve upon the shortcomings of `strtotime()`. `strtotime()` does have some very serious issues, particularly when dealing with ambiguous dates (not an issue in this case, but does trip people up). It is also very slow, because it has to work out what format to use before it even starts. If you know the format, don't use `strtottime()`. If you don't know the format, `strtotime()` is too risky to use.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `date()` function can only handle integer timestamp values; it can't process strings as input.

If you need to convert from one string date format to another, you should use the `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()` method:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::CreateFromFormat($inputString);
$outputString = $dateObj->Format('D, d M Y');
```

However, I would recommend writing your query to use MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to get the date into PHP as a numeric timestamp that PHP's `date()` function can handle:

MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourDateField) as yourDateField_timestamp FROM yourTable ...
```

Then you can write PHP exactly as you wanted:

PHP:

```
$dateObj = date('D, d M Y', $row['yourDateField_timestamp']);
```